# How can I divide one row into two?

Tags: sql, sql-server

The merchantFee has a tendertype of creditcard or debitcard which is caculated in the same row but I need to split those two amounts up to give a amount for credit and debit.
There is a row which indicates Creditcard of debitcard which is called TenderType but I cant assign the tendertype to one otherwise it doesnt work and if I use a CASE the sum does not work in the script.

Could anyone please assist?

My code:

```
USE [PAYAT]
SELECT month(t.DateCreated) AS Month,
    c.name AS [Retailer],
    h.name AS [Bill Issuer],
    count(t.RecID) AS [Total_Transactions],
    sum(t.RetailFee) AS [RetailFee],
    sum(t.Pay@fee) AS [Pay@_Fee (Incl)],
    sum(t.Pay@Fee / 1.14)AS [Pay@_Fee (excl)],
    sum(t.CashHandlingFee) AS [Cash_Fee],
    sum(t.MerchantFee) AS [Merchant_Fee]
FROM dbo.tblPay@transactions t (nolock)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tblPay@company c (nolock) ON t.RetailID = c.RecID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tblPay@company h (nolock) ON t.ClientID = h.RecID
    WHERE t.DateCreated > '2013-10-01 00:10:00.000'
    AND t.DateCreated < '2013-10-01 23:59:59.000'
    Group BY c.name,h.name, month(t.DateCreated)
    ORDER BY c.name
```

Comment: Is this for MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: Sorry I am still getting use to the site, it keeps giving me errors when I put my code in the comment section

Comment: I adjusted the code as I have it at the moment and the result is correct I just need to split the MerchantFee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You question says "split one row into two", but based on the description, I'm assuming you mean "split one column into two"... if so, I believe this is what you want:

```
USE [PAYAT]

SELECT 
    month(t.DateCreated) AS Month,
    c.name AS [Retailer],
    h.name AS [Bill Issuer],
    count(t.RecID) AS [Total_Transactions],
    sum(t.RetailFee) AS [RetailFee],
    sum(t.Pay@fee) AS [Pay@_Fee (Incl)],
    sum(t.Pay@Fee / 1.14)AS [Pay@_Fee (excl)],
    sum(t.CashHandlingFee) AS [Cash_Fee],

    -- removed
    --sum(t.MerchantFee) AS [Merchant_Fee],

    -- added case statements to separate merchant fees into two categories
    sum(CASE WHEN TenderType='CreditCard' THEN t.MerchantFee ELSE 0 END) AS [Merchant_Fee_Credit_Card],
    sum(CASE WHEN TenderType='DebitCard' THEN t.MerchantFee ELSE 0 END) AS [Merchant_Fee_Debit_Card]

FROM
    dbo.tblPay@transactions t (nolock)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tblPay@company c (nolock) ON t.RetailID = c.RecID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tblPay@company h (nolock) ON t.ClientID = h.RecID
WHERE
    t.DateCreated > '2013-10-01 00:10:00.000'
    AND t.DateCreated < '2013-10-01 23:59:59.000'
GROUP BY
    c.name,h.name, month(t.DateCreated)
ORDER BY
    c.name
    ; --added
```

Answer (score 0):

Get two different result sets and union them.  Like this:

```
USE [PAYAT]
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT month(t.DateCreated) AS Month,
    c.name AS [Retailer],
    h.name AS [Bill Issuer],
    count(t.RecID) AS [Total_Transactions],
    sum(t.RetailFee) AS [RetailFee],
    sum(t.Pay@fee) AS [Pay@_Fee (Incl)],
    sum(t.Pay@Fee / 1.14)AS [Pay@_Fee (excl)],
    sum(t.CashHandlingFee) AS [Cash_Fee],
    sum(t.MerchantFee) AS [Merchant_Fee]
FROM dbo.tblPay@transactions t (nolock)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tblPay@company c (nolock) ON t.RetailID = c.RecID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tblPay@company h (nolock) ON t.ClientID = h.RecID
WHERE TenderType='CreditCard'

UNION

SELECT month(t.DateCreated) AS Month,
    c.name AS [Retailer],
    h.name AS [Bill Issuer],
    count(t.RecID) AS [Total_Transactions],
    sum(t.RetailFee) AS [RetailFee],
    sum(t.Pay@fee) AS [Pay@_Fee (Incl)],
    sum(t.Pay@Fee / 1.14)AS [Pay@_Fee (excl)],
    sum(t.CashHandlingFee) AS [Cash_Fee],
    sum(t.MerchantFee) AS [Merchant_Fee]
FROM dbo.tblPay@transactions t (nolock)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tblPay@company c (nolock) ON t.RetailID = c.RecID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tblPay@company h (nolock) ON t.ClientID = h.RecID
WHERE TenderType='DebitCard'
) A
```

Comment: I keep getting the following error "Column 'dbo.tblPay@transactions.DateCreated' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause." and I tried putting in the group by and it does not work.

Comment: Ok I got that figured out, Thanx

Comment: Oh. Check the TenderType. I think my original answer had 'Debit' and 'Credit' but it looks like that column might have been using 'CreditCard' and 'DebitCard'.  Try this modified version.